# Drupal 7 access denied recent log messages with audiofieldrecorder module

Tags: php, permissions, drupal-7, access-denied

I get white noise when trying to record with Drupal's audiorecorderfield module which uses the nanogong recorder.

Here are the recent log messages ;

```
access denied   09/21/2012 - 22:16 node/add/gong/i18n/NanoGong_en_GB.properties  Anonymous (not verified)
access denied   09/21/2012 - 22:16 node/add/gong/i18n/NanoGong_en_GB.class  Anonymous (not verified)
access denied   09/21/2012 - 22:16 node/add/gong/i18n/NanoGong_en.properties    Anonymous (not verified)
access denied   09/21/2012 - 22:16 node/add/gong/i18n/NanoGong_en.class Anonymous (not verified)
access denied   09/21/2012 - 22:16 node/add/gong/i18n/NanoGong.class    Anonymous (not verified)
```

Top access denied errors

```
node/add/gong/i18n/NanoGong_en.properties
10  node/add/gong/i18n/NanoGong_en_GB.properties
6   node/add/gong/i18n/NanoGong.class
6   node/add/gong/i18n/NanoGong_en.class
6   node/add/gong/i18n/NanoGong_en_GB.class
2   node/add/record-podcast
```

I've tried rebuilding permissions and double checked that permissions were correct for all roles - but no luck. Anyone know what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually on the Windows 7 side. For some reason my audio recorder wasn't working correctly.